No conjugacy class of size $p^{n-1}$ in group of order $p^n$ ($n \geq 2$)
Exercise. Let $p$ be prime and $G$ a group of order $p^n$ where $n \geq 2$. Show that there is no conjugacy class of size $p^{n-1}$.
I've tried a few things, like applying the "$G$ mod center cyclic $\implies$ $G$ abelian" property. But I was not successful and I don't know how to solve it.

The size of the conjugacy class of $x$ is the index of the centralizer of $x$. The centralizer of $x$ contains at least $\langle x\rangle$ and $Z(G)$. Since $G$ is a $p$-group, $Z(G)$ is nontrivial of order at least $p$.
So you would need $C_G(x)=Z(G)$ of order $p$. But then $x\in C_G(x)=Z(G)$, so $C_G(x)=G$, which is impossible.

Wow, thank you. Seems I was blind...
